# Отображение информации через tooltip

Tags: javascript, html

Есть задача вывода регистрационного номера пользователя (SpecialNum) в tooltip, при наведении курсором мышки на иконку.
Иконка отображается только у тех пользователей, кто имеет номер регистрации. Таким образом, сначала идет иконка, а затем текст "Регистрация подтверждена" (см. скриншот):

[image: С иконкой]
Получается только добавить идентификатор (SpecialNum) пользователя в строку (на скриншоте выделил желтым):

[image: Без иконки, но с номером]

Фрагмент кода:

```
<td>
<span content="leaf:SpecialNum"></span>
<input type="hidden" content="leaf:SpecialNum" id="SpecialNum" onchange="if ($(this).val() != '') $(this).parent().find('img').show();" />
<img style="display: none;" width="15px" src="/Content/image/card.png" title="Пользователь Зарегистрирован" alt="Пользователь Зарегистрирован" />

<span content="leaf:Status"></span>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: А C# тут при чем?

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `title` поможет.

[Справка](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp)

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
p, img {
  display: block
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40" title="00002323109093">
  <p>Регистрация подтверждена</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Немного уточню суть вопроса, дело в том, что параметр leaf:SpecialNum не статичное значение, например, у Иванова 1234567, у Петрова 1111111, а у Сидорова его вообще нет, так как его регистрация пока не подтверждена. Приведенный вариант решения, необходимо скорректировать до вышеупомянутых характеристик. Еще раз огромное спасибо за Ваше время и помощь!

Comment: @Дмитрий пишите условие на вывод атрибута title на C#, тут уже сами

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй дополню ответ от **highpassion** более компактной версией и с точки зрения запросов к серверу и корректности семантики разметки:

```css
.reg {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.reg > [title] {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 14 14'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E%0A.st0%7Bfill:%23008B42;%7D%0A.st1%7Bfill:%23FFFFFF;%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Ccircle class='st0' cx='7' cy='7' r='7'/%3E%3Crect x='6' y='6' class='st1' width='2' height='6'/%3E%3Ccircle class='st1' cx='7' cy='3.5' r='1.2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="reg"><span title="00002323109093"></span>Регистрация подтверждена</p>
```

Впрочем способов заморочиться на эту тему превеликое множество. Тут вам и `:before` с `:after`, и `content:`, и `data-title=""`, и множество всего, хоть ты конкурс объявляй на самое безумное или оригинальное решение .)

Comment: Немного уточню суть вопроса, дело в том, что параметр leaf:SpecialNum не статичное значение, например, у Иванова 1234567, у Петрова 1111111, а у Сидорова его вообще нет, так как его регистрация пока не подтверждена. Приведенный вариант решения, необходимо скорректировать до вышеупомянутых характеристик. Еще раз огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: В таком случае исправьте ваш пример текущего кода до полноценной ячейки/строки таблицы и фрагмента CSS отвечающего за неё, чтобы понятно было откуда берутся эти данные.  Мы с highpassion показали вам как правильно сверстать этот фрагмент, а не как обвешать его JS (возможно безо всякой нужды). Но если вы хотите подогнать вёрстку под готовый HTML и JS, а не сделать сразу правильно, то и показывайте фрагмент ячейки/строки целиком и укомплектуйте второй строкой, где этих данных нет.